# Finding packages which have old configs installed and forcing them to use the new configs

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dpkg, aptitude

Sometimes I get messages saying that the old package still has old configs and it uses that instead of the new configuration file. Is there anyway in Debian to force packages to use new config files rather than the old ones. I want to use it as a command or an option if it's possible and when I'm happy then make it the default.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option for `dpkg` called `--force-confnew`. It might be what you are looking for.

You can use it with apt-get like this:

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" <package-name>
```

There is a good guide/explanation [**here**](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/).